# find and Highlight number in image

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am Working in web application ASP.NET .I want to highlight Searched number from image.
When I enter Consignment No like 1035200000050 in text box it displays One Image containing more then 20 Consignments.

My requirement is when image display i want to highlight the specific consignment which user enter in text box.

Does any one know How to do that. I have searched for it but i find highlight in PDF. I didn't find any demo or example for image.
Provide me link with example or code. here is image where i want to highlight text:

[image]

Comment: If you know the position on the image it should not be dificult... if not you will need some character recognition code(Optical Character Recognition-OCR). you can create your own, or use something like https://gist.github.com/yatt/915443 (which I do not know if it is working).